# Connect to Database Engine through query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-engine

When you open the SQL Server Management studio you connect to the Database engine through UI.I want same functionality through SQL query e.g. to connect to database we write Use  similarly is there any way to connect to database engine.

Comment: Connect with what? How do you mean "through SQL query"?

Comment: I want to connect to Database engine (SQL server) using Server name, User Name and Password through query in SQL Management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you cannot connect to a server using server name, database name, user id and password from a query.

What you need to do is go to the `Object Explorer`, click on `Connect` and then `Database Engine`:

[image]

Once you're connected to a server, you can switch between databases using

```
USE (database name)
```

but you cannot connect to another server in a T-SQL query, as far as I know.

Comment: I _think_ he wants to initiate a connection from the query window.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is not supported - you need to provide the credentials in the `Connect to Server` dialogue.

There is no way to have a query window open a connection to a database directly.